# Changing itemsep without using enumitem package

Tags: formatting, itemize

I know that you can change the `itemsep` of an `itemize` environment by loading the `enumitem` package. To the extend of my knowledge, this method has the disadvantage that every time I use an `itemize/enumerate` environment to manually adjust `itemsep`.

Thus, I want to ask if there is a method (preferably) or a package in which I can set `itemsep=0.2cm` (or its corresponding value in `pt`) globally (i.e. for my entire document).

Thanks in advance!

PS: A workaround is to record a macro with my settings (`itemsep`, `label`, etc..). However, I don't think that is a proper way to handle such thing

Comment: Please tell us which value you'd like to set `\itemsep` to. `0pt`? Something else?

Comment: `0.2cm` i don't know its corresponding value in `pt`

Comment: the enumitem package has declarations to set the default values as well as the optional argument that allows them to be set in each case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is that i cannot load `enumitem` because it is incompatible with my document class ( i am using `beamer` with the `metropolis` theme). that's why i am asking for a non-package solution

Comment: That isn't what you say in the question, there you say you don't want to use enumitem as it means setting it on each list. Normally you can just set the lengths globally with `\setlength` but the class may impose some defaults (and you hadn't mentioned beamer until that comment)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right. but my point is whether an alternative to `enumitem` solution might exists. but i should mention that i am using `beamer` class to avoid any confusion and solutions that might not be applicable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine \@listi (I use a large 2cm to show the effect):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep 4.5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
            \topsep 9\p@   \@plus3\p@ \@minus5\p@
            \itemsep 2cm \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@} %adapt
\let\@listI\@listi
\@listi
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item b
  \item b
  \item b
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]