# Setting items separation in enumerate to pre-defined length (beamer)

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize

I am trying to set global parameters to control items separation in `enumerate` and `itemize` environments. The command (from [LaTeX Beamer: Define \itemsep globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225736/latex-beamer-define-itemsep-globally/225737#225737))

```
\xpatchcmd{\itemize}{\def\makelabel}{\setlength{\itemsep}{\heightItemSepI}\def\makelabel}{}{}
```

Works well to set the separation for `itemize` to a predefined height of `\heightItemSepI`

The command (from [Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer))

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@listI}{\itemsep3\p@}{\itemsep=0.5em}{}{} % this sets the space globally (for itemize or enumerate)
\makeatother
```

Works for both `enumerate` and `itemize`, but it cannot accept a predefined height and, if put there, it will throw the error 'missing number, treated as zero'.

My question is how to combine the good features of both approaches? I do not like to enter the numbers directly in commands because I like to set parameters outside the commands modifying packages/classes codes. This helps me set things up quickly when I come back after a while. Also, I use predefined lengths for certain calculations about the layout of my documents.

I know that `enumitem` allows for easy customization of these parameters but `enumitem` in beamer can lead to 'TeX Capacity Exceeded' errors

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlength{\heightItemSepI}
\setlength{\heightItemSepI}{0.3cm}
\newlength{\heightItemSepII}
\setlength{\heightItemSepII}{0.2cm}
\newlength{\heightItemSepIII}
\setlength{\heightItemSepIII}{0.15cm}

\makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\itemize}{\def\makelabel}{\setlength{\itemsep}{\heightItemSepI}\def\makelabel}{}{}
    \g@addto@macro\@listii{\itemsep \heightItemSepII}
    \g@addto@macro\@listiii{\itemsep \heightItemSepIII}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@listI}{\itemsep3\p@}{\itemsep=1em}{}{} % this sets the space globally (for itemize or enumerate)
\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

    \blindlistlist[1]{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Long Lists}

    You can insert a very long nested list by using a page-wide frame with multicols

    \blindlistlist[3]{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/global-setting-of-spacing-between-items-in-itemize-environment-for-beamer/249958

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459482/36296

Comment: @samcarter The last link works well for both `enumerate` and `itemize` with predefined length, but it sets the separation for all levels of lists with no control on which level we apply the new separation

Comment: I just tried and in its current form it only set the spacing for the first level itemization, not for sublists.